# VSTO Outlook: How to handle hover event on a recipient in the "To" "BCc" and "CC" fields in compose window

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Is there any way to handle the hover event (when mouse is over) on a recipient in the "To", "BCC" or "CC" fields? If so how?

[image]

Comment: No, there is no such event.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I was trying to handle the event that opens the popup window by default when you hover on the mouse on a recipient because in that window it is showing the email address so you can add to your favorites, add as a contact, access his/her linkedin profile, etc. And I would like to change the email address that is appearing in that window. Can't do it with some kind of hack either?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko See the update in my post. I have put an screenshot where you can see the popup window I am referring to.

Comment: Nope, there is nothing in any API exposed by Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.